# Find all solutions $(x,y,z)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all solutions $(x,y,z)$ of nonnegative integers $x,y,z$ satisfying the system of equations $$x^{3}-y^{3}-z^{3}=3xyz$$ $$2(y+z)=x^{2}$$

It's Just For Sharing a New Ideas, Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

$$x^3-y^3-z^3=3xyz$$is true only when  $$x-y-z=0$$so$$2x=x^2$$
Hence $x=0$ or $x=2$. But if $x=0$ then $y+z=0$ is possible for non-negative integers only when $y=0$ and $z=0$. Hence the possible solutions are $$(0,0,0)$$
and $$(2,\alpha,2-\alpha)$$

Comment: You should prove first sentence. It's true and well-known, but it may be useful.

Comment: sorry for using it directly.